# How to write a login script in python via an interactive CLI

Tags: python

I am writing a python script to log into (not ssh/telnet) a remote system (not a Linux) and run commands.
Below is an example that does the things manually.

```
root@centos (Centos 7.3) ➜  ~ shell_tool --cmd "<cmd1>;<cmd2>" 
//interactive shell
System address: 10.0.0.1
Username: admin
Password: 123456

<output>
```

Besides to login and run commands, I also want to save the output. shell_tool --cmd ";" >>output.txt does not work here because there is interactive shell after the command.

Can someone help with the script?

Comment: Have a look at [pxssh](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) in [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: It's not a ssh connection, it's a private shell tool. I want the user to input the system address, username and password, pexpect seems to not help here.

Comment: You can use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) to read a password without showing the letters typed. You can use pexpect to drive any command line utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create `mockup.py` that will be a stand-in for whatever program you are trying to control:

```
import getpass

hostname = input('System address: ')
username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
if password == 'good_guess':
    while True:
        line = input('mockup> ')
        if line == 'quit':
            break
```

**Sample Interaction**

```
$python mockup.py
System address: bogus
Username: nobody
Password: 
mockup> fake command
mockup> quit
```

We can write a Python program that will control `mockup.py` and log all interaction to a file named `session.log`:

```
import pexpect
import getpass

hostname = input('hostname: ')
username = input('username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
prompt = 'mockup> '

with open('session.log', 'wb') as log_file:
    session = pexpect.spawn('python3 mockup.py')
    session.expect_exact('System address: ')
    session.sendline(hostname)
    session.expect_exact('Username: ')
    session.sendline(username)
    session.expect_exact('Password: ')
    session.sendline(password)
    # Start logging to a file here
    session.logfile_read = log_file
    session.expect_exact(prompt)
    session.sendline('fake command')
    session.expect_exact(prompt)
    session.sendline('quit')
    session.expect_exact(pexpect.EOF)
```

**Sample Interaction**

```
$ python3 use_pexpect.py 
hostname: bogus
username: nobody
password:
```

**Contents of session.log**

```
mockup> fake command
mockup> quit
```

This should be enough information to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to hide the plaintext of password in session.log? Or totally remove the login process in session.log, only show the output of commands.

Comment: @Chris.Zhou I changed the solution so that it starts logging after the login interaction is complete. Also, I changed the logging to use `logfile_read` so that only the data received from the program is logged. If you want to continue to log everything, use `session.logfile = log_file`.

Comment: @David.Cullen Don't know why the script doesn't work well on my side. Issue is regarding "session.expect_exact(prompt)". I also added it in my script session.expect(‘*>’), it doesn’t work as well. The prompt in my system is like “username@hostname>”
When I removed two "session.expect_exact(prompt)” and “session.sendline('quit’)”, the script works well.

Comment: Hopefully it is obvious that you did not provide enough information for me to create a `mockup.py` that duplicated your environment. Also, my answer was designed to give you a starting point for you to adapt to your specific problem. At the minimum, you would have to change `prompt = 'mockup> '` to reflect your specific situation.